# How to Add NAudio to my Project?

Tags: c#, dll, naudio

so, sorry if this is a stupid question, but I've been working with audio a lot, and I'm going to try out NAudio, so I went to the [website](http://naudio.codeplex.com) (which, by the way, is blocked in Chrome), and downloaded it. Then I searched and searched through the files. Most of the folders don't even include any `.dll` files, and those that did didn't have one that made sense to reference to. So then I went back to the website and looked around, and I've searched and searched on the internet for things relating to "how to add NAudio to your project" or "How to link NAudio", and I've come up with nothing.

How can I add NAudio to my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website you linked to is on Codeplex which is depricated. The current place for NAudio is on github: https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/wiki/Getting-Started

Set a package reference to NAudio on nuget.org: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio/

This will pull in the package and set references to the correct dlls

Answer (score 3):

Run this in your package manager.

```
Install-Package NAudio -Version 1.8.4
```

It will automatically add all required reference, you can remove the version flag "-Version 1.8.4" to install latest version